# Проблема с переносом кода с c++ на java

Tags: android, java, c++

Добрый день.

Переношу код с c++ на java (android). Столкнулся с проблемой при переносе функции алгоритма Евклида:

```
long Nod(long a, long b){
    while (a && b)
        if (a >= b)
           a %= b;
              else
           b %= a;
    return a | b;
}
```

Дело в том, что компилятор ругается на while (a && b). Код ошибки:

```
    The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) long, long
```

Почему для типа long такая операция невозможна и как можно поправить ситуацию?

P.S. В java ещё новичок.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас два числа, а вы их объединяете логическим и. Тут более строгое преобразование типов. В си у вас `a==0 == false`, тут `a==0 === 0L`, поэтому компилятор не понимает операцию логического И между двумя лонгами, т.к. её тупо нету. Замените на `(a!=0)&&(b!=0)`, чтобы достичь аналога c++.